# Shell command in ruby: Path problems

Tags: ruby, shell, zsh, environment

The following shell script should check my ruby project for lint coffeescript and scss.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "\n== Checking if CoffeeScript is lint =="
checks << system("coffeelint -f .coffeelint.json ./app/assets/javascripts/**/*.coffee")

puts "\n== Checking if SCSS is lint =="
checks << system("scss-lint ./app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.scss")

exit 1 if checks.include?(false)
```

But the output of running that script in *zsh* is the following:

```
== Checking if CoffeeScript is lint ==
fs.js:849
  return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './app/assets/javascripts/**/*.coffee'
  at Error (native)
  at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:849:18)
  at findCoffeeScripts (/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/io.js/v2.3.3/lib/node_modules/coffeelint/lib/commandline.js:79:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/io.js/v2.3.3/lib/node_modules/coffeelint/lib/commandline.js:247:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/io.js/v2.3.3/lib/node_modules/coffeelint/lib/commandline.js:254:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:430:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/io.js/v2.3.3/lib/node_modules/coffeelint/bin/coffeelint:34:5)
  at Module._compile (module.js:430:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:471:10)
  at startup (node.js:117:18)
  at node.js:948:3


== Checking if SCSS is lint ==
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.scss
```

It seems like the current working path is wrong, but at least `puts system("pwd")` is showing the correct directory from where the relative paths in the arguments should be reachable.

**What's going on here?**

Comment: Seems that your globs (`**/*.coffee`) are not expanded. You sure that coffeelint can handle those? (ZSH should have expanded them, though. Must be that `system` uses bash or something)

Comment: Why for God’s sake you expect `system` to execute `zsh`? It executes simple `/bin/sh` that lacks double splat expansion. Use `system("#!/bin/zsh\n........")`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: why the shebang? Can't one just call zsh and directly pass command to be evaled?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Indeed. `zsh -c 'blah'`.

Comment: Why not just write a shell script instead of wrapping it in Ruby?